# How to create a dialog or popup which fades out?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I want to create a popup/dialog which appears at the bottom left of my screen (my activity) and which fades out after a certain amount of time similar to a Toast, but such that it is more complex than a Toast in that it has its own layout (images etc). Anyone know whether this is possible with DialogFragment or PopupWindow or any other class? And, if so, which class might be best for this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Toast with a custom view: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html